# Couldn’t load x.dll or one of its dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have a legacy Visual C++ library. I compile it using Visual Studio 2015 and use it in another applications. Everything is OK on my development environment, but on my production server I'm getting **"couldn’t load ManagerApi.dll or one of its dependencies"** exception. It works fine if I install Visual Studio 2015 with Visual C++ components on server. But I don't want to do that.
Here is my list of installations on server machine:

[image]

What do I have to install to use the library without exceptions?

Here is the dependency walker screenshot for the dll:

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Would help to know which DLL. I assume something you compile yourself. Get Dependency Walker and check which DLL is missing. http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Here is the name of the dll: ManagerApi.dll. Yes, as I compile the dll myself. I tried dependency walker but I don't think this is not a good way to use a dll on a machine. What if I have to install my app to another server? Do I have to copy and paste the required dlls again? I think that there must be an installation package that is contained by the visual studio installation

Comment: Only use the Walker to see what's missing, don't copy them by yourself to target machines. Installation package should always handle that.

Comment: I added a screenshot of dependency walker. What do I have to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess, but looking at your dependency walker screen, you're missing MSVCP140D.DLL which is a debug version of the c++ runtimes which don't get installed by the VS2015 redist package.  If you recompile your DLL as release rather than debug it should be ok.  Alternatively, if you use an installation packager such as Installshield that checks dependencies, it should sort the problem for you.